# Using target offset to clear a range of cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear a range of 5 cells when changing another. For example: H5 is changed, J5:J10 is cleared. This works a treat in clearing J5 when H5 is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Left(Target.Address(, False), 1) = "H" Then Target.Offset(, 2).ClearContents
End Sub
```

However this does not clear the 4 cells below. I was wary of using a function to specify the range as I've got multiple rows of data in H. So for example if H24 changes, J24:J29 are cleared, which goes on for about 200 rows...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In one of the comments, you are saying that `H5:H10` is merged. Could you kindly share which contents you would like to clear in this particular case? One of the 5-cell ranges, `J5:J9` or `J6:J10`? Or is it the 6-cell range `J5:J10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Offset`-function returns a range with the same size than the original Range, just at a different place. To increase (or decrease) the size of a range, you can use the `Resize`-function. So basically, you need to combine both functions.

I don't want to argue with you about how to check for the column, but I think using `If Target.Column = 8 Then` is much easier.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 Then   ' Col H
        Dim destRange As Range
        Set destRange = Target.Offset(0, 2).Resize(5, 1)
        Debug.Print destRange.Address
        destRange.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Be aware that `Target` may contain more than one cell (eg via Cut&Paste), you probably need to handle that.

Comment: This one does not seem to work, not sure why though :/

Comment: I see from your comment on another answer that you deal with merged cells. `Offset` has  a problem with merged cells. Which cells are merged: Cells in column H or J? And are they merged horizontal for vertical? Can you give an example?

Comment: Hello! They are merged in column H, so cells H5:H10 are merged into one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Left(Target.Address(, False), 1) = "H" Then ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Offset(, 2), Target.Offset(5, 2)).ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Okay with merged cells offset gets weird and even offsetting the topleft cell of the merged area (`Target.MergeArea(1, 1)`) will give bad results so we need to create the range ourselves.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.MergeCells = True Then
        If Left(Target.Address(, False), 1) = "H" Then ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Offset(0, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Row + 5, Target.MergeArea(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Column)).ClearContents
    Else
        If Left(Target.Address(, False), 1) = "H" Then ActiveSheet.Range(Target.Offset(, 2), Target.Offset(5, 2)).ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I hardcoded the `5` into the row change if you need it to be the size of the merged area you will need to get the difference in rows from the top to the bottom of the merged area.

Comment: Ah, I take it back, it clears the contents of the below 10 cells. though the reference cell is a merged one. Would that make a difference?

Comment: This works every time. Thank you so much. Now to get my bird brain around how it actually works it's magic. Much appreciated :)

Comment: It is creating a new range by offsetting `target` by 2 columns: `h5` to `j5` then it gets the row and column and adds 5 to the row so `range(j5:j10)` you just can't do the second half of that using `offset` because it will always use the lowest part of the merge cell to do the offsetting even if you specify the topleft cell of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear Cells on Any Side of Merged Cells

- The colors in the image show which contents will be cleared in column `J` if a value in a cell in column `H` is changed (manually or via `VBA`).

[image]

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim doEnableEvents As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "H2"
    Const ColOffset As Long = 2
    
    Dim irg As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set irg = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        doEnableEvents = True
        Dim arg As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each arg In irg.Areas
            For Each cel In arg.Cells
                If cel.MergeCells Then
                    With cel.MergeArea
                        .Cells(1, 1).Offset(, ColOffset).Resize(.Rows.Count) _
                            .ClearContents
                    End With
                Else
                    cel.Offset(, ColOffset).ClearContents
                End If
            Next cel
        Next arg
    End If

ProcExit:
    If doEnableEvents Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Sub testMultiArea()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("H2,H7")
    rg.Value = 500
End Sub
```